# Using Linq query when we get record by id how can i assign that value to another column?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Here I wrote simple `where` condition linq query I'm getting data from the database, but I want to assign that data to another column.

**Employee**

```
public class Employee
{
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
}
```

Linq query:

```
public Employee GetEnqDetails(int EnqId)
{
    if (EnqId != null)
    {
        var x = from n in db.Employee 
                where n.Id == EnqId
                select n;
        return x.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here from `Employee` table whatever data I'm getting I want to assign that data to another class as

```
public class EmailContent
{
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Here subject =x.Name +"" x.Email  How can i assign that value

Comment: and what body contents like `body = x.?`

Comment: `var first = x.FirstOrDefault();` now create `EmailContent` from that `var ec = new EmailContent(); ec.Subject= first.Name ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are getting the Employee details from the method `GetEnqDetails()` you can create a new instance of the `EmailContent` with those details:

```
var employ = GetEnqDetails(101);
if (employ != null)
{
    EmailContent emc = new EmailContent() { Subject = String.Format("{0} {1}", employ.Name, employ.Email), Body = "" }; 
    // proceed with emc 
}
```

If you don't want to use the filtered employee details, only the requirement is to instantiate the `EmailContent` with the employee details means you can change the method like the following:

```
public static EmailContent GetEnqDetails(string EnqId)
{
    if (EnqId != null)
    {
        return db.Employee.Where(n => n.Id == EnqId)
                          .Select(x => new EmailContent()
                          {
                              Subject = String.Format("{0} {1}",
                              x.Name, x.Email),
                              Body = ""
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Update as per the comment:

There is a DataType mismatch as specified in the comment, that is EnqId is int and n.Id is string. Please correct them accordingly. I just changed the parameter as string in my code. Because the comparison (`if (EnqId != null)`) is meaning less in the value is integer. So if you are forwarding with `int` remove the condition

Comment: @sujith, your code doesn't compile bcoz `EnqId` is int and `n.Id` is string. here you got an compile time error

Comment: @ershoaib: absolutely, I have updated the answer with my comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `GetEnqDetails` method parameter should `string` because your `Id` in `Employee` class is of DataType `string`.

And then you have to project your query result to your `EmailContent` class like

```
public EmailContent GetEnqDetails(string EnqId)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnqId))
    {
        var x = from n in db.Employee
                        where n.Id == EnqId
                        select new EmailContent { Subject = n.Name + " " + n.Email, Body = "get any property by typing n." };
        return x.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```